# Creating a 2d array with numbers 1-16 in random order

Tags: arrays

I'm getting an out of bounds exception when filling the square array. I'm not really worried about the top part because I know that isn't the best way to do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] square = new int[4][4];
    boolean isMagicSquare = true;
    int[] num = new int[16];
    for (int i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
      num[i - 1] = i;
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(num.length);
      int temp = num[randomIndexToSwap];
      num[randomIndexToSwap] = num[i];
      num[i] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(num[i]);
    } {
      for (int col = 1; col <= square.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 1; row <= square.length; row++) {
          square[row][col] = num[((col - 1) * 4 + row) - 1];
        }
      }
```

Comment: It looks like your code should not compile because of the extra "{" on the sixth line from the end.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of this

```
for (int row = 1; row <= square.length; row++)
{
square[row][col] = num[((col-1)*4 + row)-1];
```

`row <= square.length` means you go up to the size of length (included), but if you have length `10`, then your array have indexes `0..9`. When you try to access `arr[10]` it will fail on bound exceptions.

You should always cycle through array as this: `for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)`

For array of arrays as this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
  for (int col = 0; col < square[row].length; col++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the exception, but I assume it is in the last block.  If this is Java the arrays will be 0-indexed.  I have changed the last block so that it should not go outside of the array.  You will have to confirm that the num[...] calculation is still what you want.

```
 for (int col = 0; col < square.length; col++)
 {
       for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
       {
            square[row][col] = num[((col)*4 + row)-1];
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not subtracting one from `row` and `col` when you use them on the fourth to bottom line like you are when you initialize your array in your first For loop.

What you should be doing is used 0 based indexing in all of your loops.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] square = new int[4][4]; 
    boolean isMagicSquare = true;
    int [] num = new int[16];

    for (int i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = i;
    }

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(num.length);
        int temp = num[randomIndexToSwap];
        num[randomIndexToSwap] = num[i];
        num[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }


    for (int col = 0; col <= square.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row <= square.length; row++) {
            square[row][col] = num[(col*4 + row)];
        }
    }
}
```